# Trying to pass addresses to simple variables to a function (pointers & loops) In C

Tags: c, function, loops, pointers, variables

I'm trying to declare variables in my main() and then use their address and point to them in a function so that my function doesn't return any thing and all changes of the variable in the function goes straight to the main(). But every time I run this program it asks for x and then for "how many terms to use".. If I write 0 it works and goes to the if statement and if i write and bigger number than 0 than it works but if I write a negative number like -1 it moves on and ends he program??? does anyone have any idea?

Here's my basic code:

> ```
> void getInput(double *,int *);
>
> void main()
> {
>     double x;
>     int n;
>
>     getInput(&x,&n);
> }
> void getInput(double *N, int *X)
> {
>  N = 0;
>  printf("Please enter a real value for x: ");
>  scanf("%lf", &X);
>  while(N <= 0)
>  {
>      printf("How many terms to use: ");
>      scanf("%ld", &N);
>      if (N <= 0)
>      {
>          printf("The value of a must be greater than %d\n", N);
>      }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: 'scanf("%ld", &N);' incorrect format specifier for double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
scanf("%lf", &X);
```

to:

```
scanf("%d", X);
```

Inside the `getInput` function, `X` is *already* a pointer.

The same for the other `scanf`, where you should change `scanf("%ld", &N);` to `scanf("%lf", N);`.

Also change `N = 0` to `*N = 0` and `if (N <= 0)` to `if (*N <= 0)`.

You also mixed up the `%ld` and the `%lf` format specifiers.

Your compiler should have warned you.

And finally change:

```
printf("The value of a must be greater than %d\n", N);
```

to

```
printf("The value of a must be greater than 0");
```

If you enter e.g. `-1` you don't want the text `The value of a must be greater than -1` to be displayed.

Unrelated: 
it's `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: @DogLoaf enable warnings for your compiler (-Wall for gcc).

Comment: @DogLoaf I edited the question, there are far more problems that I initially spotted.

Comment: I now changed the printf thing your wright i did something dumb also tried adding * where you put them and now it skips the scanf("%lf", N); part. I think it's because it skips the while because of the variable n not having 0 being assigned to it. I don't know?

Comment: oups never mind I found it, i put &x,&n the wrong way its &n,&x

Comment: Sorry, it's `scanf("%d", X);` instead of `scanf("%ld", X);`. And yes, you've mixed up x and x. One good reason more to name your variables with understandable names such as `nbofitems` instead of `n`.